# how memory is allocated if inheritance is used?

Tags: c#, inheritance, heap-memory

I have a class

```
class A
{
   public void Greet()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hii");
   }
}

class B : A
{
   public void Greet2()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
   }
}

class Program
{
   public static void main(string args[])
   {
      B b = new B();
      b.Greet();
      b.Greet2();
   }
}
```

How will memory be allocated in the heap space for the base class and derived class. Will the derived class have all the methods of base class or will it have the object of base class?

Comment: There is a difference between how methods are handled and how memory for the variables is handled. One continuous memory area is allocated for all the fields of the type, including all fields of base classes. Additionally, there is a block of memory in memory for the type, allocated once, which contains the virtual method table, which includes all virtual methods of the type and base classes.

Comment: Non-virtual methods are not handled in any particular way. Instead, the original method, defined once, will be called even if called through a derived class, just passed a `this` reference to the derived type.

Comment: When B is instantiated the base class, which is class A is also called the class constructor, and memory is allocated separately to classes A and B

Comment: @RezaJenabi can you please elaborate the explanation

Answer (score 0):

> Will the derived class have all the methods of base class

Memory is NOT allocated for methods at all. Method is allocated for storage, ONLY, and the object inclused a pointer to the type. And the TYPE - the class, not the instance - has the methods. All methods get an invisible pointer to the class memory (this) if they are not static.

When an object is created, the memory for this particular type storage is allocated, not more, not less.

Comment: My doubt is, when `B b = new B();` is called the object `b` can call the methods of the  base class too. Then where will the base class instance of the derived class be stored?

Comment: In the type, not in the class, as I clearly said. The type contains the jump tables for the methods including all base class methods.